# Find multi-line block using grep and/or automator with BBEdit

Tags: automator, text-editor, search

I have an xml file output from WordPress.

I have BBEdit as my main search tool.

I am on a Mac running 10.7.4

I am trying to find a muli-line block of text that starts with `<item>` and end with `</item>`

In the block, there must be `<wp:status>publish</wp:status>` and `<wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>`

Does anyone have any idea how I would find that using GREP or Automator?

*(Sorry I don't have enough rep to make better tags)*

Comment: [Posting questions on multiple sites isn't generally allowed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Can you delete either this question or the [one at Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/465973/find-multi-line-block-in-wordpress-xml-file-using-bbedit-and-or-automator-on-mac)?

Comment: It won't let me delete it

Comment: I ended up using Filemaker pro and two related sql tables to create a new xml file. very messy. it took weeks to figure out.

Answer (score 7):

You can do multiline [greps in TextWrangler](http://www.americashorsedaily.com/images/Applications/TextWrangler.app/Contents/Resources/TextWrangler%20Help/grep/grep.htm) using various pattern modifiers (i, m, s, and/or x)

e.g.

searching for

`<item>(?s).*?<\/item>`

will match across lines.

After that, you can modify your regex to be more elaborate.

Comment: What is this: `(?s)` - found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927930/meaning-of-s-in-regex - "Turn on "dot matches newline" for the remainder of the regular expression. (Older regex flavors may turn it on for the entire regex.)"

Comment: If you press the question mark button and scroll down, so see all modifiers like this. This is described as "Allow "." to match a line break". It's just a modifier, so when it's present at the beginning of your query, it would work as well: `(?s)<item>.*?<\/item>`.